Default text in Word in Repeating Section Content Controls changes back to "Click or tap…"
I'm designing a form in Word that requires a few repeating sections for things like the people who have reviewed a procedure.
I've been able to create individual fields as Plain Text Content Controls (I don't want the people filling the forms to style the text usually), and I've been able to change the standard default text from "Click or tap to enter…" to the information I'm asking the form user to enter (e.g. "ReviewerName", "ReviwerTitle", etc.).
This has worked fine for individual form fields, but when I create a Repeating Section Content Control, when the user adds a new row for a second entry, all the text reverts to "Click or tap…"
This isn't the end of the world of course—the user has literally just filled out that line in the section above, but is there some way to change this behaviour, and have the repeated section start with the default text that I've specified for the fields within it?

The method below works here. I would guess that you may not actually be modifying the Placeholder Text correctly (possibly just inserting text in each CC when you have togo into Design Mode to do it). If that isn't the problem, can you (a) describe your own sequence, and (b) maybe clarify whether or not you are using (say) Content controls pulled in from Sharepoint, or mapped controls, that kind of thing).

Insert a 1-row table, and put a Plain Text Content Control in each
cell. So you have:

Click on Design Mode and modify the Placeholder texts: 

Click again on Design Mode to exit that mode, select the table row,
and insert the Repeating control 

Type a value in each plain text content control: 

Click on the "add a new copy" cross at the bottom
right of the table:



Well that worked, which is very curious.
My sequence was to select existing text within cells in a table already created ("AuthorName", "AuthorTitle", etc.) and make each into a Plain Text CC.
Then I'd select the entire row, and make it into a Repeating Section CC.

@Alan - I just tried that, just to to be sure that selection+insert control actually does not the placeholder text, but here it does not (e.g., if I start with "value A" in cell 1, select, insert field,, I see "value A", but if I delete that text I see the standard placeholder. So either "modifying the text in Design mode" is what was missing before, or iit will remain a mystery :-)
